# Python modbus library that supports extended address spacing?

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus, modbus-tk

I have a Modbus RTU device that has information stored within non-standard data addresses.

For example, it stores read values (32-bit IEEE-754 float, [converter link](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)) in register number 1003 - 1004.

I *think* this means I can no longer use standard Python + Modbus RTU libraries like `modbus-tk` and `pymodbus`.

What can be done in this situation?

---

**Device Specifics**

- Device: E+E Elektronik's CO2 sensor, series [EE872](http://www.epluse.ch/en/products/co2-measurement/co2-sensor/ee872/)
- [User Manual](http://www.epluse.ch/fileadmin/data/product/ee872/BA_EE872_e.pdf) (section 5.2 contains Modbus RTU information)
- Device is plugged into Windows 10 machine with Python 3.6

Comment: You can use pymodbus binary decoder class to convert the 4 registers to float . Refer https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/examples/common/modbus_payload.py

Answer (score 1):

You can use different type of data-format with modbus-tk by giving it as optional argument of the `execute` method

```
    # Read and write floats
    # master.execute(1, cst.WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS, starting_address=0, output_value=[3.14], data_format='>f')
    # logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 0, 2, data_format='>f'))
```

The data_format is based on python `struct` module. Expected values are listed here.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#format-characters

I hope it helps